# Titanium CLI run command missing

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to run my Titanium application on a android device, but hen I run the command `ti run -p android -T device` I receive the error `[ERROR] "run" is an unrecognized command.`.

How can I run my app on android device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
appc run
```

[Appcelerator Command-Line Interface Reference - Run](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_Command-Line_Interface_Reference-section-43294287_AppceleratorCommand-LineInterfaceReference-run)